# Iterate over minute interval in week

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I'd like to generate a matrix across a week with a specified interval set in minutes. Each cell would be computed from a list of objects, which hold a datetime and a value. If there are no objects with a datetime matching a cell, that cell should be set to 0.  For instance, an interval of 240 minutes with the records shown in the example below would generate the following matrix:

```
day,section,output
0,0,0
0,1,0
0,2,6
0,3,0
0,4,39
0,5,0
1,0,0
1,1,0
1,2,-6
1,3,0
1,4,0
1,5,0
2,0,0
2,1,0
2,2,0
2,3,0
2,4,0
2,5,0
3,0,0
3,1,0
3,2,0
3,3,9
3,4,0
3,5,0
4,0,0
4,1,0
4,2,0
4,3,0
4,4,0
4,5,60
5,0,0
5,1,0
5,2,0
5,3,0
5,4,0
5,5,0
6,0,0
6,1,0
6,2,0
6,3,0
6,4,0
6,5,0
```

I've included an example below to show how it could be done naively if it was simply done on a daily basis without setting empty cells to 0.

```
import itertools
import datetime as dt

def _group_date(records, _fun):
    for _, chunk in itertools.groupby(records, key=lambda r: _fun(r.datetime)):
        yield chunk


class Record(object):
    def __init__(self, value, datetime):
        self.value = value
        self.datetime = datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':

    operator_func = lambda val: val*3
    min_interval  = 240    

    records = [Record(value=2, datetime=dt.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 8, 12)),
               Record(value=13,datetime=dt.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 17, 14)),
               Record(value=-2,datetime=dt.datetime(2015, 1, 6, 10, 27)),
               Record(value=5, datetime=dt.datetime(2015, 1, 8, 14, 1)),
               Record(value=-2, datetime=dt.datetime(2015, 1, 8, 15, 37)),
               Record(value=20,datetime=dt.datetime(2015, 1, 9, 20, 53))]

    # example just to show how it could be done naively if it was simply on a daily basis
    # without setting empty cells to 0
    day_records   = _group_date(records, lambda d: d.isocalendar()[2])
    output        = []
    for day in day_records:
        day_output = 0
        for rec in list(day):
            day_output = day_output + operator_func(rec.value)
        output.append(day_output)

    print output
```

This has to run in a specific environment, which only has core packages. So sadly no pandas or numpy. It has to run on ~100M of these class objects (more complex than in this MWE) so efficiency is also somewhat important, but getting something that simply runs is the most important thing.

Comment: Instead of running script for a week, did you consider making script that would be automaticaly run (via cron) in desired intervals with results being appended into file?

Comment: This is an old dataset so that's not really an option. But thanks for the suggestion!